# For which values of $k$ the matrix is not diagonalizable over $\Bbb R$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I'm not quite sure how to start this exercise. What are the steps I should follow in order to solve it?

> For which values of $k$ the matrix is not diagonalizable over $\Bbb R$?
>
> $$\begin{pmatrix} k+3 & 0 & 0 \\ -k-3 & k & k+3 \\ -k-3 & k & k+3 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: You should start by reviewing what you know about diagonalizability. So: what do you know about when a matrix is, or isn't, diagonalizable over the reals?

Comment: The dimension of the eigenvectors should be equal to the dimension of the matrix (3)?

Comment: Eigenvectors don't have a dimension. Matrices don't have a dimension. Vector spaces have a dimension. I think what you are trying to say is that the number of linearly independent eigenvectors should equal the number of rows of the (square) matrix which, in our case, is indeed 3. So: can you work out the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors of this matrix?

Comment: This is what I was trying to say, yes. I've found the eigenvalues are $0$, $k+3$ and $2k+3$, and the corresponding eigenvectors are: $$\begin{pmatrix} \frac{k}{k+3} \\ 1 \\1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \frac{-k-3}{k} \\1\end{pmatrix}$$ So I've found that for $k = -3, 0$ the matrix is not diagonalizable. Is that right?

Comment: At each of those values one of the vectors is undefined. You need to investigate those values of $k$ separately.

Comment: Yes, as @amd says, you need to look at the matrix for $k=0$ and find its eigenvectors to see whether it is diagonalizable, and then do the same for $k=-3$. I would encourage you to do that, and then to write up what you find, and post it as an answer.

Comment: Making any progress, Infected?

Comment: If I plug in $k=-3$ in the original matrix, it is diagonalizable. However, I had to say that $k \neq -3$ in order to find the eigenvalues (I had to divide by $k+3$), so I'm a bit confused. Can I ask you for a solution so I'll be able to understand it better?

Comment: What that tells you is that your way of finding the eigenvalues doesn't work when $k=-3$, but that doesn't matter. What matters is that you have shown that the matrix is diagonalizable when $k=-3$. Now, what happens when $k=0$? By the way, if you want to be certain I see a comment, you have to put @Gerry into it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson When $k=0$ the matrix is not diagonalizable. So, is the final answer $k=0$?

Comment: If you've done everything else right, then, yes.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for your help! I've posted my answer to my own question, will appreciate your feedback :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is my first answer so I apologize if it's not the best looking answer.*

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix} k+3 & 0 & 0 \\ -k-3 & k & k+3 \\ -k-3 & k & k+3 \end{pmatrix}$

**We'll find the eigenvalues of the matrix:**

$ 0=|A - \lambda I| = \begin{vmatrix} k+3 & 0 & 0 \\ -k-3 & k & k+3 \\ -k-3 & k & k+3 \end{vmatrix}$

$= (k+3-\lambda)(k^2+3k-\lambda k - \lambda k - 3\lambda + \lambda ^2-k^2-3k)= \lambda(k+3-\lambda)(\lambda - (2k+3))
$

Therefore:

$
\lambda_1 = 0, \lambda_2 = k+3, \lambda_3 = 2k+3
$

**Now, we'll find the corresponding eigenvectors:**

**For $\lambda_1 = 0$:**

$
(A-0*I) = \begin{pmatrix} k+3 & 0 & 0 \\ -k-3 & k & k+3 \\ -k-3 & k & k+3 \end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow\begin{pmatrix} k+3 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & k & k+3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix} k+3 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & k & k+3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} \Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
(k+3)x=0 \\ ky=(-k-3)z
\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}
x=0 &(k \ne -3) \\ y=\frac{-k-3}{k}z & (k \ne0) \\ z= Free
\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 0\\\frac{-k-3}{k}\\1\end{pmatrix}
$

**For $\lambda_2 = k+3$:**

$
(A-(k+3)*I) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -k-3 & -3 & k+3 \\ -k-3 & k & 0 \end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -3-k & k+3 \\ -k-3 & k & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -3-k & k+3 \\ -k-3 & k & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} \Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
(-k-3)y=(-k-3)z \\ (-k-3)x=-ky
\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}
x=\frac{-k}{-k-3}z &(k \ne -3) \\ y=z \\ z= Free
\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} \frac{k}{k+3}\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}
$

**For $\lambda_3 = 2k+3$:**

$
(A-(2k+3)*I) = \begin{pmatrix} -k & 0 & 0 \\ -k-3 & -k-3 & k+3 \\ -k-3 & k & -k \end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow\begin{pmatrix} -k & 0 & 0 \\ -6 & -3 & 3 \\ -3 & k & -k \end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix} -k & 0 & 0 \\ -6 & -3 & 3 \\ -3 & k & -k \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} \Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
-kx=0 \\ -6x-3y+3z=0 \\ -3x+ky-kz = 0
\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}
x=0 & (k \ne 0)\\ y=z \\ z= Free
\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}
$

*Note: Since if $\lambda_3 = 0$ there will be repeated eigenvalues ($\lambda_1=0$), we'll check what happens if $k=-\frac{3}{2}$.*

*Therefore, for $k=0,-3$ the matrix is suspected to be not diagonalizable.*

We'll check these values:

**$\color{blue}{k=0}:$**

$A_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -3 & 0 & 3 \\ -3 & 0 & 3 \end{pmatrix}, \lambda_1 = 3, \lambda_2=0$

For $\lambda_1 = 3$:

$(A-3I) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -3 & -3 & 3 \\ -3 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} \Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
x=0 \\ y=z \\ z=Free
\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}
$

For $\lambda_2 = 0$:

$(A-0*I) = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 0 & 0 \\ -3 & 0 & 3 \\ -3 & 0 & 3 \end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} \Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
x=0 \\ y=Free \\ z=0
\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}
$

*The number of eigenvectors (2) is different from the number of matrix rows (3). Therefore, the matrix is not diagonalizable for $k=0$.*

**$\color{blue}{k=-3}:$**

$A_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -3 & 0 \\ 0 & -3 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \lambda_1 = 0, \lambda_2=-3$

For $\lambda_1 = 0$:

$(A-0*I) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -3 & 0 \\ 0 & -3 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} \Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
x=Free \\ y=0 \\ z=Free
\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}
$

For $\lambda_2 = -3$:

$(A-(-3)*I) = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -3 & 3 \end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} \Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
x=0 \\ y=z \\ z=Free
\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}
$

*The number of eigenvectors (3) equals to the number of matrix rows (3). Therefore, the matrix is diagonalizable for $k=-3$.*

**$\color{blue}{k=-\frac{3}{2}:}$**

$A_3 = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{3}{2} & 0 & 0 \\ -\frac{3}{2} & -\frac{3}{2} & \frac{3}{2} \\ -\frac{3}{2} & -\frac{3}{2} & \frac{3}{2} \end{pmatrix}, \lambda_1 = 0, \lambda_2=\frac{3}{2}$

For $\lambda_1 = 0$:

$(A-0*I) = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{3}{2} & 0 & 0 \\ -\frac{3}{2} & -\frac{3}{2} & \frac{3}{2} \\ -\frac{3}{2} & -\frac{3}{2} & \frac{3}{2} \end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} \Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
x=0 \\ y=z \\ z=Free
\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}
$

For $\lambda_2 = \frac{3}{2}$:

$(A-\frac{3}{2}*I) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -\frac{3}{2} & -3 & \frac{3}{2} \\ -\frac{3}{2} & -\frac{3}{2} & 0 \end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} \Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
x=-z \\ y=z \\ z=Free
\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} -1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}
$

*The number of eigenvectors (2) is different from the number of matrix rows (3). Therefore, the matrix is not diagonalizable for $k=-\frac{3}{2}$.*

**Finally, we can say that the matrix is not diagonalizable over $\Bbb R $ for $k=0, -\frac{3}{2}$ (only).**

Comment: Good. I wonder whether there isn't one more case that needs to be checked. When $0=2k+3$, that is, when $k=-3/2$, you get a repeated eigenvalue, and I think you need to check whether there are enough independent eigenvectors.

Comment: You are right. The matrix is also not diagonalizable for $k=-\frac{3}{2}$. I will edit my answer soon.